# Why is $\sum\limits_{k:|2k/l-m/l|\geq\epsilon/2}\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{2l-m}{l-k}}{\binom{2l}{l}}\geq 2e^{-\epsilon^2l/8}$

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

This is stated in an article on the uniform convergence of probabilities of events to their relative frequencies. The idea behind the question is that I have a measurement on a sample of size $2l$ where event $A$ occurs $m$ times and I want to know the probability that the relative frequency of event $A$ in the first half of the sample differs at least $\epsilon/2$ from the relative frequency of event $A$ in the second half of the sample